# How to handle RestKit nested array of ID references to objects that don't exist yet?

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I have an app that has Users. Users belong to an Account. An Account can have multiple Projects, and within those Projects a subset of Account.Users are assigned as Collaborators via a 'Collaboration' object. I retrieve this information and store it in CoreData using RestKit, however I'm having some trouble hooking up relationships - presumably due to the order that the objects are stored.

My JSON for a Project looks something like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Some Project Name",
  "collaborations": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "collaborator_id": 1,
      "permission_group_ids": [ 1, 2 ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "collaborator_id": 2,
      "permission_group_ids": [ 2, 3 ]
    }
  ],
  "permission_groups": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Admin"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Manager"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Employee"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, as you can see, I have nested references to other objects specific to this Project. Each Collaborator belongs to a set of permission groups specific to a Project. I have my mappings for a collaboration (the class is called `ProjectCollaborator` internally) set up as below. I use similar code elsewhere in the app successfully.

```
// These mappings (and others) work fine.
[map addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"permission_group_ids" : @"permissionGroupIds"}];
[map addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"collaborator" withMapping:[User collaboratorMapping]]];

// This mapping works fine in other places, but not here.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[self entityName] inManagedObjectContext:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
NSRelationshipDescription *groupRelationship = [entity relationshipsByName][@"permissionGroups"];
RKConnectionDescription *connection = [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:groupRelationship attributes:@{@"permissionGroupIds" : @"serverId"}];
[map addConnection:connection];
```

My request is set up as follows.

```
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].responseDescriptors];
```

The response descriptors on the shared manager are added like so:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[...
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[Project showResponseMapping] method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"projects/:serverId" keyPath:@"project" statusCodes:successCodes]
...]];
```

And this is the relevant parts of the `Project showResponseMapping`:

```
+(RKEntityMapping *) showResponseMapping
{
    static RKEntityMapping* map = nil;
    if (map == nil)
    {
        map = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:[self entityName] inManagedObjectStore:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore]];
        map.identificationAttributes = @[ @"serverId" ];
        [map addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"name" : @"name" }];
        [map addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"permission_groups" toKeyPath:@"permissionGroups" withMapping:[PermissionGroup mapping]]];
        [map addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"collaborations" toKeyPath:@"collaborations" withMapping:[ProjectCollaborator mapping]]];
    }
    return map;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the `collaboration.permissionGroups` relationship is never set up - specifically, the `NSSet` for that property is empty. My `permissionGroupIds` attribute is correctly populated, the relationship to the user (`collaboration.collaborator`) is correctly set up. I use a similar strategy of an array of IDs referencing existing objects in other responses and the mappings for those works successfully.

What I *suspect* is happening is that the `collaborations` key is being handled first, and all the children of that are being stored, but related PermissionGroups with the supplied IDs cannot be found, so the attempt to set up the relationship is abandoned. Later, the `permission_groups` key is mapped and those groups are stored. I have unit tests that confirm the PermissionGroup objects are being correctly stored.

There are, to my eye, two solutions to this problem, neither of which I can find a way to do - I'd prefer the first option, if possible:

- I could specify an order in which to parse the keys (I've already tried adding the mappings in different orders)
- I could have RestKit (or CoreData?) create an 'empty' object in CoreData which will get populated later when the `permission_groups` key is populated

Are either of these options possible, or is there a better solution?

Comment: You can't do order. The empty, or stub, option is the one, but only applies if you get ids now and other objects later (different URL request). All your data is nested so you should have response descriptors to create all the objects and then your foreign key mapping runs last (it does) to connect them up. So - what response descriptors do you currently have and what objects are created as a result of this 1 request?

Comment: I've added what I _think_ you're looking for, Wain - I recently inherited this code, and I've not worked with RestKit before. I've been building out unit tests for these mappings, and according to those both my PermissionGroup and Collaboration objects are created successfully.

Comment: [Here's a quick gist](https://gist.github.com/adamsp/dc839edcb2a9d4e0d106) of my unit tests.

Comment: Is the JSON a single dictionary with a dictionary for the project key? I'm not sure but I guess the connection is run at the end of the internal mapping...

Comment: The JSON from the server will look like `{ "project": { ... } }` (hence the `keyPath="project"` on the descriptor) where as the file I'm using for my unit test looks similar to what I posted above, without the top-level "project" key - since I'm just testing the project mapping. Your comment about the connection running at the end of the internal mapping - you mean it should map each key (name, collaborations, permission groups, etc) _then_ create relationships? Does my test case perhaps run too early in the chain?

Comment: Added an answer, but it is a bit 'try it and see' unfortunately, interesting situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally RK takes all of the connection mappings from all mappings to process and runs them all at the very end, but I haven't checked if that is the case.

If not, and it looks like not from your situation, then you need to ensure that all objects are created before you try to connect them.

This is something I haven't tried in your exact configuration, but I'd try creating 2 other response descriptors and putting them in the array before your current one. Each would use the internal mapping (group then collab) and would use the keypath to drill in to the associated array of data.

The main issue is that I haven't checked if the request operation (or rather the mapping operation it will start) uses the response descriptor array in order. If it does then all of the inner objects will be created, then the project will be created and connected to them, then they will be connected to each other.

Comment: So, the tests I was running are just mapping tests and don't use the descriptors (from what I can tell). That said, I've got some other tests which mock the API responses and I had a play with those and was seeing the same results. I tried this solution (adding a descriptor for the "project.permission_groups" keypath before the "project" one) and am unfortunately _still_ seeing the same result - an empty set of relations.

Comment: `[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[PermissionGroup mapping] method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"projects/:serverId" keyPath:@"project.permission_groups" statusCodes:successCodes]`

Comment: Next step is turning on trace logging and seeing what it says about finding the objects to connect to and the order it tries in

Comment: So, uh. Oops. It appears I wasn't ever mapping the `id` attribute of the permission group, which meant that there was never a matching object to create a relationship against! Turning on logging is what helped me track that down, though - thanks for that suggestion, and it really should've been my first port of call. Your understanding that the relations are created _after_ the mappings appears to be correct; I don't need the additional descriptor for my mocked API response, and this works correctly in my mapping unit test too.

Comment: ...good grief I have the id mapping tested in a different test and it fails when I remove this fix too, not sure how I missed that one. Thanks a lot for your help Wain, and sorry for wasting your time on what turned out to not actually be an interesting problem after all.